# Customize OAuth token endpoint response wso2Carbon

Tags: json, oauth, wso2, access-token, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to figure out how to change/customize the standard OAUTH token response in WSO2Carbon.

The standard response is something along the lines of:

```
{ "access_token"  : "...",
  "token_type"    : "...",
  "expires_in"    : "..."
}
```

Now I have found how to add fields to get them included into the access token generated/JWT, but I am trying to figure out how to add elements to this actual json object.. so the response is something say like:

```
{ "access_token"  : "...",
  "token_type"    : "...",
  "expires_in"    : "...",
  "myfield"       : "..."
}
```

I have found documentation for other systems explaining how to approach this, but they have all been for other products... So how do I customize the token request to add values to the json obect returned as desired?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no extension point for this in IS. But you can modify its `oauth2.war` webapp. The source can be found [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth). make sure to use the correct tag which matches to your IS version.

You can try setting a new parameter [like this](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/endpoint/token/OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java#L181).